# Codeigniter CSS not updating with new code

Tags: css, codeigniter

I have a project in codeigniter which worked very good until today.
When I edit my css file it works and gets updated but when I'm trying to load it onto the site it's not showing the updated version. I did get back to FileZilla and checked if I missed something but no, the code I updated with is there, no problems.

I have tried to clear my cache in my web browser but it does not seem to solve the problem.

What is causing this?

Comment: StackOverflow is not exactly the place for such question, but did you try to reload the CSS files? (hit ctrl+F5 in your browser).

Comment: @Dekel Yes I tried that, didn't work..

Comment: without looking at your code it's really hard to help.

Comment: @Dekel What code do you need? The CSS files.. or which ones?

Comment: everything to understand what exactly isn't working. you might have a problem in you css/js/html/php - I really don't know.

Comment: But everything is updating on server but it does not show in browser.. @Dekel

Comment: so obviously you have some problem there...

Comment: @Dekel My friend having the same problem on his computer tho

Comment: ok... so i guess I'm right :)

Answer (score 1):

Cloudflare caused this! If anyone have the same problem and using cloudflare you'll have to change cache settings.